# Connection between nativescript and MongoDB (mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nativescript

I am new in mobile development world and right now trying to understand few basic things.
I did a simple login nativescript app and from backend side did a login logic with mongoose (MongoDb) and express. But now I don't know how to proceed... How do I connect between backend and app?

Thank you in advance,
Emil

Comment: I found this very interesting article which may help you a lot http://mean.expert/2016/05/27/angular-2-ultimate-native-app/

Comment: Yes, rad this... but still didn't understand how it is works exactly. Reached until 'Configure DataSource' (included) and the stacked. Now can't understand what I should do in my app to get this work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose an API from your backend, I'll assume you have done this (or can find this out - it's very well documented).

So from the client {N} you will need to access the API, calling whichever end-points you need. If you were using a JWT type approach, you should use the http module in nativescript, which might look something like this:

```
var http = require("http");
var result;

http.request({
    url: "https://myBackend.org/api/post",
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    content: JSON.stringify({ username: "ValueOne", password: "ValueTwo" })
}).then(function (response) {
    result = response.content.toJSON();
    console.log(result); //result.message would have the clients auth token
}, function (e) {
    // console.log("Error occurred " + e);
});
```

You could then store the token (in persistent storage with the application-settings module) and add it to the header of any request to a different API endpoint to interact with your backend as an authenticated user.

Alternatively, you can use one of the cloud backend SDKs, e.g. [Azure Mobile Services](https://github.com/PeterStaev/nativescript-azure-mobile-apps) or [Firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) which make your life much easier.